# Wordpress gives 404 when page url is requested if additional get parameters are added

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm using wordpress on centos7 and **nginx**

`http://example.com/welcome/` --> shows the welcome page
but `http://example.com/welcome/?message=activated` --> shows 404

why is that? is there a way to circumvent it?

Comment: have you tried using a different parameter other than message just to see if it's all types of values?

Comment: Can you share your nginx error logs?